# Flask on click with href location issue

Tags: javascript, html, flask

Im using flask and want to redirect a user to a specific html page when they click a button:

```
<button class="therapist-button" onclick='location.href='{{ url_for('therapist') }}''>Talk with your own personal therapist</button>
```

How do I do this? I'm getting. A "unterminated string literal" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is: `window.location.href`

But the URL should be quoted. Check the source code for the generated page if in doubt. I would try something like this:

```
onclick="window.location.href = '{{ url_for("therapist") }}'"
```

(Not tested but hopefully works)

Although I would avoid Javascript personally and just use a plain `<a href>`, but it can be styled like a button

Comment: The was a red error line below this, but it works...javascript man

Answer (score 1):

First: I think that since it is a listener directly on the markup, you need double quotes:

```
<button onclick="yourFunction()">...</button>
```

And second: What are you doing or what it seems that you are trying to do is to concatenate a string, since `location.href` is being used with quotes like a string `'location.href'` you should try it probably using `window.location`.

I think this could work:

```
<button class="therapist-button" onclick="window.location.href = url_for('therapist')">Talk with your own personal therapist</button>
```

Comment: it gets rid of the error, but it doesn't redirect. I think there might be a flask issue

Comment: Could it be. Here is a link to W3Schools with a simple redirect (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp) try it with a hardcoded URL to discard any problem with your `url_for` function